# Paypal Payments Pro not working while in test mode

Tags: checkout, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

I just set up Paypal Payments Pro and I cant get test mode to work. I have tried several of the recommended credit cards that paypal documentation shows, but when I  test it in live mode, it declines (im assuming because its in live mode) but when I switch it to test mode, all that happens is I get a spinner that never ends and no message.